# Octopus Deploy not updating web site

Tags: iis-7, web-deployment, octopus-deploy

I am using octopus deploy to push my website into environments

the code gets to the server but octopus doesn't change the web application to point to the new directory.

e.g.

MVC4WebSite is a web application mapped to the C:\Sites\dev\MVC4WebSite\1.0.0.0

I deploy my package

the new code appears at C:\Sites\dev\MVC4WebSite\1.0.0.1

I expect that MVC4WebSite would be mapped to the C:\Sites\dev\MVC4WebSite\1.0.0.1 but it is still mapped to  C:\Sites\dev\MVC4WebSite\1.0.0.0

I get this message in the logs.

'Could not find an IIS website or virtual directory named 'MVC4WebSite' on the local machine. If you expected Octopus to update this for you, you should create the site and/or virtual directory manually. Otherwise you can ignore this message.'

I have definitely created that site (as a web application).

Specs
Win Server 2008 r2
IIS7
Octopus Version 1.0.30.1340

Comment: Great question. Worked for me...http://octopusdeploy.com/documentation/features/variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok it looks like I didn't interpret the instructions properly.

I interpreted the term site as being any code deployed as a Virtual Directory or a Web Application...what they mean, correctly, is the actual site eg. "Default Web Site"

I needed to define a custom variable to override the OctopusWebSiteName pre-defined variable with the value "Default Web Site/MVC4WebSite".

What a waste of an afternoon :(